csf -d <IP> will block an IP for a while but then it is somehow gone again from the csf.deny list some time later
I keep seeing the same attacker in my apache logs ffrom the same two IP addresses. I block both the IPs using the command
csf -d <IP>

Then I check the /etc/csf/csf.deny file and those two new IPs are in there and the malicious traffic has stopped.
A few days later I notice the malicious activity has started up again and I check the apache logs to find that it is the same two IPs. When I loop in the /etc/csf/csf.deny file again those two IP addresses are somehow gone.
Why are these not staying blocked and how can I permanently block these IP addresses from ever accessing my server again?

After getting no answer here and researching more I found vague solutions suggesting the use of a comment on the line of the csf.deny file that you don't want to be deleted.
Through further testing I was able to confirm that if I added - do not delete - to the end of the comment on the line containing the IP that I wanted to keep blocking then that line would not get deleted.
e.g. if I run the command:
csf -d 1.2.3.4
... then I will find the following line in the csf.deny file:
1.2.3.4 # Manually denied: 1.2.3.4 (GEO/Location/Info)
But that line will be gone tomorrow unless I modify it to read:
1.2.3.4 # Manually denied: 1.2.3.4 (GEO/Location/Info) - do not delete -
I still don't know why it would be deleted or if there is a better way to do it but this appears to be working for me so far. Any more info on this and/or a better solution would be appreciated.
